# MOTD stopped working at SSH success Login

Tags: ssh, shell, ubuntu-16.04

I'm struggling to figure out why my MOTD stopped working. I customized my MOTD by adding a script in /etc/update-motd.d

Some informations :

OS : Ubuntu 16.04 
sshd conf :  PrintMotd yes, UsePAM yes

/var/run/motd.dynamic - WORKS FINE

run-part /etc/update-motd.d/ - WORKS FINE TOO

But when I login by SSH pubkey nothing appear, just my Banner and the prompt.

Comment: What you mean by "stopped working" What you mean by "WORKS" for the paths/commands. Does it work if you remove your script? And with password authentication?

Comment: By stop working I mean, while I was working on this machine on another thing the MOTD was ok and "without any raison" stoped working. And WORKS mean if I run theses commands the MOTD appear. I don't authorize password authentication on this server. Thanks for you help